# Image send with retrofit to WCF is broken

Tags: image, wcf, retrofit

i am trying to send an image using retrofit 2 using the code below but the image i received is broken and cannot be opened using windows photo viewer. You have two screenshots below, the first is the content i get parsed as string and the second is the message i get when i try to open the image.
I have tried different options reading the stream of the sent image but none works. One is the code in wcf an two other options i used is the code that is commented but none of them works. Hope someone could help me.

```
        @Multipart
        @POST("PostImageJSON")
        Call<String> PostImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part report_image);



                    MediaType imageType = MediaType.parse("image/*");
                    File file = new File(ImagePath+"/savedReportPhoto.jpg");

                    if(file.exists()) {
                        RequestBody requestBodyImage = RequestBody.create(imageType, file);
                        MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadedImage", file.getName(), requestBodyImage);
                        Call<String> callSendImage = api.PostImage(image);


                        progress.setTitle("Procesim");
                        progress.setMessage("Duke procesuar..");
                        progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
                        progress.show();

                        callSendImage.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String responseimg = response.body();

                                    progress.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong with the request to the server !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }

            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/PostImageJSON", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            String PostImage(Stream postedImage);

        public String PostImage(Stream postedImage)
        {
  //Here i parse the stream as string for testing purposes
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postedImage);
            string res = reader.ReadToEnd();

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("F:\\image.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(res);
            }


    //First option i have tried
            //do
            //{
            //    bytesRead = postedImage.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            //    ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            //} while (bytesRead > 0);

            //using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("F:\\postedImage.png"))
            //{
            //    ms.WriteTo(fs);
            //    fs.Close();
            //    ms.Close();
            //}

            //Second option i have tried
            byte[] buffer = new byte[19127];
            postedImage.Read(buffer, 0, 19127);
            FileStream f = new FileStream("F:\\savedReportPhoto.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            f.Close();
            postedImage.Close();
            return "Recieved the image on server";

  //Third option i have tried
            //FileStream f = new FileStream("F:\\savedReportPhoto.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            //postedImage.CopyTo(f);
            //f.Close();
            //postedImage.Close();
            //return "Recieved the image on server";

          }
```

[The image content i recieve as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4nUN.png)

[When i try to open the photo on windows photoviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32vrq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i have found the solution after struggling for a week, the solution was not to send the image separate from the other data but to encode it as base64 string and send it along with the object and then decode it in the server and do what ever you want.

This is the method in the retrofit interface:

```
 @POST("PostBanderolDataJSON")
    Call<ReportPostData> PostData(@Header("Authorization") String serviceToken,@Body ReportPostData reportdata);
```

and here i am sending the data along with encoding the image:

```
            ReportPostData rpd = new ReportPostData();

            rpd.setBanderolnr(banderoNr);
            rpd.setPharmacy(pharmacy);
            rpd.setPlace(place);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = Common.loadImageFromStorage(ImagePath);
            if(bmp!=null) {
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                rpd.setImageFile(encodedImage);
            }
```

and then adding the image to the object as you can see above with the line:

```
rpd.setImageFile(encodedImage);
```

and the enqueing the object and send it as usual with retrofit.

Hope someone find this useful